# Unity: SteamVR TeleportArc not colliding correct in Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, interaction, htc-vive, steamvr

i am using Unity 2019.4.9f1 with SteamVR. The Teleporting-System works as expected in Playmode. When I build, there are some strange collision-glitches with the TeleportArc. The point at the end does not collide correct with mesh. The colliders seem to be underneath the floor(while still working properly), or the wall mesh etc. I am also able to see the TeleportPoint through mesh.

Editor-Playmode:

[Working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6dX5.png)

Build:

[TeleportArc not colliding with Wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APAMn.png)

[TeleportArc not colliding with Floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBfkN.png)

[TeleportPoint visible through Wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoOfV.png)

Has anyone experienced errors like these? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I would like to show these images in my posting but I am not allowed to because of my karma.

Comment: i guess it has something to do with the render layers... but could not figure it out yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution:
It is a problem with the Material of the Teleporting Prefab. The URP-MaterialSwitcher was not working correct. I changed the materials manually and now everything is working fine.

https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steamvr_unity_plugin/issues/875